# C - Trying to scanf hex/dec/oct values to check if they're equal to user input

Tags: c

So, I'm new to C and this is my ever first project for class. I basically need a program that asks the user how many questions he wants, then retrieves a positive max 8 bit number which can be in oct/dec/hex (it's random) and then asks the user to convert it to to a random base. For example, If I get a decimal number It will randomly ask me to convert it to hex or octal. At the end of every question, it says if my convertion is right or wrong and in the end of the program it shows how many questions I got right.

All works well until I start typing random letters/characters when it asks me to convert to other than hex. If it asks me to, for example, convert octal to decimal, if I enter a single letter it will sometimes say It's right and it also skips questions and continues the cycle until it gets an hex.

I can't really figure out what can I do. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int rightanswers = 0;
    int answer;
    int nquestions;

    printf("Number of questions:");
    scanf("%d", &nquestions);

    srand((unsigned int) time(NULL));
    unsigned char questions[nquestions];

    for (int i=1; i<=nquestions; i++)
    {
        questions[i] = (rand()%255)+1;
        int randomnumb = (rand()%6)+1;
        switch(randomnumb)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("\nConvert 0%o to base 10:", questions[i]);
                scanf("%d", &answer);
                if (answer == questions[i])
                {
                    rightanswers++;
                    printf("Right!");                                       
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Wrong!");                       
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("\nConvert 0%o to base 16:", questions[i]);
                scanf("%x", &answer);
                if (answer == questions[i])
                {
                    rightanswers++;
                    printf("Right!");                                       
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Wrong!");                       
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("\nConvert %d to base 8:", questions[i]);
                scanf("%o", &answer);
                if (answer == questions[i])
                {
                    rightanswers++;
                    printf("Right!");                                       
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Wrong!");                       
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("\nConvert %d to base 16:", questions[i]);
                scanf("%x", &answer);
                if (answer == questions[i])
                {
                    rightanswers++;
                    printf("Right!");                                       
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Wrong!");                       
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                printf("\nConvert 0x%x to base 8:", questions[i]);
                scanf("%o", &answer);
                if (answer == questions[i])
                {
                    rightanswers++;
                    printf("Right!");                                       
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Wrong!");                       
                }
                break;
            case 6:
                printf("\nConvert 0x%x to base 10:", questions[i]);
                scanf("%d", &answer);
                if (answer == questions[i])
                {
                    rightanswers++;
                    printf("Right!");                                       
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Wrong!");                       
                }
                break;  
        }
    }
    printf("\nYou got %d conversions right!", rightanswers);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you never validate the **return** of `scanf`, how can you have any confidence that you are processing valid data from that point forward?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin how can I validate the return of scanf? I'm trying to look it up but I'm getting more confused!

Comment: Example `if (scanf("%d", &answer) != 1) { /* handle error */ }` or better, `int rtn; rtn = scanf("%d", &answer); if (rtn == EOF) { /* user canceled input (ctrl+d) */ } else if (rtn == 0) { /* handle matching or input failure */ } else if (rtn == 1) { /* good input -- do your thing */ }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing from my comments. `scanf` (and family) give new C programmers no end of trouble with user input because of the numerous pitfalls associated with `scanf`. Largely because the conversion specifiers behave differently regarding handling of leading *whitepace* (e.g. `space`, `tab`, `newline`, etc..) and the programmers failure to validate the **return**. The return validation is critical because what is left in the *input buffer* (e.g. `stdin`) depends on whether a successful conversion takes place.

`scanf` returns the number of successful conversion. (e.g. `scanf ("%s %d", strvar, &intvar)`) contains `2` *conversion specifiers* (`%s` & `%d`). If a string and integer are successfully converted and stored in the variables provided, the **return** is `2`. Anything less indicates either a *matching failure* or *input failure* or the user canceled input by manually generating an `EOF` with <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> on windoze).

If a conversion fails, either due to a *matching failure* (mismatch between input type and conversion specifier) or an *input failure* (there wasn't enough input for each conversion specifier), reading from `stdin` stops, no further characters are read from the *input buffer* and all characters are left -- just waiting to torpedo your next call to `scanf`.

Further, you must account for the `'\n'` (generated by the user pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>) that is left in the *input buffer* after each call to `scanf`. Some *format specifiers* will consume leading *whitespace* while others (such as character format specifiers will not), in fact `%c` will happily take the `'\n'` left in `stdin` **as your next input**.

Specifically, the numeric format specifiers (e.g. `%d, %x, %o, %lf, ...`) will all ignore leading whitespace, so you do not have to specifically remove whitespace before your next `scanf` call. For all others you do. This accounting for what remains (or could remain) in `stdin` is critical for the use of `scanf` for input. Otherwise you are just asking for input appearing to be skipped or... an infinite loop. (you can handle whitespace in the way you craft your *format string*)

All of which is why a *line oriented* input function like `fgets` is the recommended way to handle user input. It will read up to **and including** the trailing `'\n'` which provides a simple check for whether all input characters provided by the user where properly read. (after the user input is validated, you then parse whatever you need from the buffer filled by `fgets` (or POSIX `getline`)

But since you will encounter `scanf` many times, it is well worth the time it takes to read (and understand) `man scanf`. Yes it's a bit dry reading, but it is the only thing that will explain exactly where the `scanf` pitfalls are.

With that in mind, the following provides two examples (modifications to your code) to show you how to approach handling input with `scanf`. The first reading of `nquestions` just shows a general approach to validating integer input with `scanf`, checking the return, handling the user cancellation (which generates an `EOF`), and finally emptying any characters that remain with a helper function `empty_stdin()` that simply reads from `stdin` until a `'\n'` (generated by the user pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>) or `EOF` is found.

The remainder of the user input is handled by the helper function `getintvalue` (since you don't want to duplicate the validation code over-and-over again in your code). `getintvalue` takes the prompt to display and the *format string* as arguments, but essentially just does the same thing that was done for `nquestions` in a function.

Other changes. You don't need an array for `questions[]`. A simple `int` value will do. You don't need to duplicate code in each `case` of the `switch`. (that has been moved to the end). The remaining changes and issues are addressed in the comments in-line, below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define PRMTSZ 128  /* if you need a constant define one */

/* or use an enum to define several */
enum { NSWITCH = 6, QMAX = 256 };

/* function to get integer value from user.
 * prompt user with 'prompt', read value with format 'fmt'.
 * returns int value or EOF on user cancelation of input.
 */
int getintvalue (const char *prompt, const char *fmt);

/* simple function to empty remaining chars from stdin */
void empty_stdin();

int main (void) {

    int rightanswers = 0,
        nquestions = 0;

    srand (time(NULL));

    /* example input loop -- loop continually until valid input or EOF */
    for (;;) {
        int rtn = 0;

        printf ("Number of questions: ");
        if ((rtn = scanf ("%d", &nquestions)) == EOF) {
            fprintf (stderr, "warning: user canceled input.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        empty_stdin();  /* remove all remaining chars from stdin */

        if (rtn == 1)   /* good input */
            break;

        /* handle matching or input failure */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
    }

    /* loops are ZERO based in C */
    for (int i = 0; i < nquestions; i++)
    {
        /* declarations 1st in each block, for C89 portability - Win7, etc. */
        char prompt[PRMTSZ] = "";               /* buffer for prompt */
        int randomnumb = rand() % NSWITCH,      /* values 0 - 5 */
            question = rand() % QMAX,           /* values 0 - 255 */
            answer = 0;

        switch (randomnumb)
        {
            case 0:
                sprintf (prompt, "\nConvert 0%o to base 10: ", question);
                /* let's use a getintvalue to validate user int input */
                if ((answer = getintvalue (prompt, "%d")) == EOF)
                    return 1;
                break;
            case 1:
                sprintf (prompt, "\nConvert 0%o to base 16: ", question);
                if ((answer = getintvalue (prompt, "%x")) == EOF)
                    return 1;
                break;
            case 2:
                sprintf (prompt, "\nConvert %d to base 8: ", question);
                if ((answer = getintvalue (prompt, "%o")) == EOF)
                    return 1;
                break;
            case 3:
                sprintf (prompt, "\nConvert %d to base 16: ", question);
                if ((answer = getintvalue (prompt, "%x")) == EOF)
                    return 1;
                break;
            case 4:
                sprintf (prompt, "\nConvert 0x%x to base 8: ", question);
                if ((answer = getintvalue (prompt, "%o")) == EOF)
                    return 1;
                break;
            case 5:
                sprintf (prompt, "\nConvert 0x%x to base 10: ", question);
                if ((answer = getintvalue (prompt, "%d")) == EOF)
                    return 1;
                break;
            default:
                fprintf (stderr, "error: something went wrong in switch.\n");
                goto badswitch;
                break;
        }
        if (answer == question) {
            rightanswers++;
            printf ("Right!\n");                                       
        }
        else
            printf ("Wrong!\n");

        badswitch:;
    }

    /* always end with '\n' for POSIX compiant EOF */
    printf("\nYou got %d conversions right!\n", rightanswers);

    return 0;
}

int getintvalue (const char *prompt, const char *fmt)
{
    int value = 0;

    /* input loop -- loop continually until valid input or EOF */
    for (;;) {
        int rtn = 0;

        printf ("%s: ", prompt);
        if ((rtn = scanf (fmt, &value)) == EOF) {
            fprintf (stderr, "warning: user canceled input.\n");
            return rtn;
        }
        empty_stdin();  /* remove all remaining chars from stdin */

        if (rtn == 1)   /* good input */
            break;

        /* handle matching or input failure */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
    }

    return value;
}

void empty_stdin()
{
    int c;

    do
        c = getchar();
    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
```

The following are the various validation runs showing proper handling of bad input or user cancellation at various stages of the program.

**Example When all Goes Right**

```
$ ./bin/inttestscanf
Number of questions: 4

Convert 218 to base 16: : da
Right!

Convert 0325 to base 10: : 213
Right!

Convert 0xe to base 10: : 14
Right!

Convert 0x39 to base 8: : 71
Right!

You got 4 conversions right!
```

**Example When User Cancels on Number of Questions**

```
$ ./bin/inttestscanf
Number of questions: foo
error: invalid input.
Number of questions: bar
error: invalid input.
Number of questions: warning: user canceled input.
```

**Example When User Enters Invalid Input**

```
$ ./bin/inttestscanf
Number of questions: 4

Convert 023 to base 16: : no good
error: invalid input.

Convert 023 to base 16: : 13
Right!

Convert 0xc7 to base 8: : foo
error: invalid input.

Convert 0xc7 to base 8: : 307
Right!

Convert 0353 to base 16: : eb
Right!

Convert 0x76 to base 10: : f8
error: invalid input.

Convert 0x76 to base 10: : 118
Right!

You got 4 conversions right!
```

(**note:** think about what happens if `scanf` expects a hex value and the user enters an arbitrary string starting with `a-f`?)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: I'm very enlightened right now! Thanks for your time and explanation!

Comment: Glad I could help. If the answer was useful to you and answered your question, you can accept the answer by selecting the top-left corner. Good luck with your coding.

Answer (score 1):

If `scanf` encounters something it cannot assign, it stops and returns. The variable you are trying to assign will not be changed - but you check its value as if it was read. It will simply contain whatever was in it from before, or random stuff.

To use scanf, you need to *always check its return value*, it tells you how many variables were assigned. Only if this count shows your variable *was* really assigned should you access its content.

Note that after a failed scanf the ‘unreadable’ data will still be in the input stream, and the next scanf will try to read the same data again.