# Free memory correctly

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I just want to know if this memory that I allocated to the pointer passed to `readItem()` is being `free`d correctly in the `main()`, and if it´s wrong, what should I do to make it right.

Thank you for the help, and have a great day!

```
typedef struct Item
{
    char* itemName;
    int quantity;
    float price;
    float amount;
} Item;

void readItem(Item* ptr);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Item sample;
    Item* p_sample = &sample;

    readItem(p_sample);
    printItem(p_sample);

    free(p_sample->itemName);
}

void readItem(Item* ptr)
{
    int size;
    printf("\n Specify the amount of letters of the product name: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    ptr->itemName = (char*) malloc (size * sizeof(char));

    if (ptr->itemName != NULL)
    {
        printf("\n Specify the name of the product (MAX %d letters): ", size);
        scanf("%s", ptr->itemName);

        printf("\n How many products do the company have? ");
        scanf("%d", &(ptr->quantity));

        printf("\n How expensive is the product? ");
        scanf ("%f", &(ptr->price));

        ptr->amount = (ptr->price)*(ptr->quantity);

    }
    else {
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Found it -- yes your use of `free()` is correct -- your use of `malloc` isn't. In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714). Further `sizeof(char)` is defined as `1` and should be omitted. You cannot use any user-input function correctly unless you ***check the return***.

Comment: It´s unnecessary to cast the return of  `malloc` because the computer is going to do automatically for me, right?

Comment: I heard from my friends that this program is causing a memory leak. What should I change to make it right? And what is a good way of checking my return if not using a function to print out all the interesting variables?

Comment: It is unnecessary to cast the return of `malloc` because any pointer may be converted to or from type `void*` (a `void` pointer) without a cast. `malloc` returns type `void*` (the beginning address to the block of memory allocated). Your friend is wrong. You have a single allocation `ptr->itemName = malloc (size);` which is then freed, `free(p_sample->itemName);` before the pointer `p_sample->itemName` is lost. (while memory is freed on program exit -- good job for creating good habits and freeing the memory you have allocated!) It is far easier to develop good habits than to break bad ones...

Comment: You should not `exit(-1)` returning a negative value to your shell. C defines two macros `EXIT_SUCCESS` (`0`) and `EXIT_FAILURE` (`1`) that should be used instead. The values `0` and `1` are the only two values C defines for returning to indicate success/failure. Further POSIX specifies that only `0` or positive values in the range of `unsigned char` be returned to the shell with those greater than `127` generally reserved for specific purposes. So return `0` or `1` to the shell.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the information contained in the comments above -- your biggest problem is you are allocating one-too-few bytes of memory. When you are allocating storage for a string, you must allocate `length + 1` bytes to provide room for the *nul-terminating* character. With you `size` above<sup>1</sup> you are only allocating enough storage for each of the characters, but not room for the *nul-terminating* character. You must allocate `size + 1` bytes.

Additionally, you must validate every user input by checking the return. If you fail to check the return you are inviting *Undefined Behavior* if the user accidentally enters an incorrect character instead of a digit for any of your numeric input. To validate each input when using `scanf()` you must check that the return equals the number of conversions specified, e.g.

```
void readItem (Item *ptr)
{
    int size;
    
    printf ("\nSpecify the amount of letters of the product name: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &size) != 1) {              /* validate every user input */
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    ...
```

That applies to all inputs. You should also consider changing the return type of `readItem` from `void` to something that can indicate success or failure of all input. (a simple `int` and return of `1` or `0` works). That way instead of calling `exit` on an input or matching failure, you can choose to handle the error and recover instead of exiting.

Additionally, after taking input with `scanf()` you should empty any characters that remain in `stdin` until a `'\n'` or `EOF` is encountered. This is one of the primary pitfalls with using `scanf()` for user input<sup>1</sup>. This is also why it is recommended user input be read with a *line-oriented* function such as `fgets()` or `getline()`. To handle this situation when using `scanf()` a simple helper function can be called after each input to empty `stdin`, e.g.

```
/* function to input stdin to end of line or EOF */
void empty_stdin (void)
{
    int c = getchar();
    
    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}
```

Now you can ensure there are no extraneous characters left in `stdin` that will cause your next input to fail. Completing the input of `size`, you would do:

```
    printf ("\nSpecify the amount of letters of the product name: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &size) != 1) {              /* validate every user input */
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    empty_stdin();              /* empty all extraneous characters from stdin */
    ...
```

(**note:** normally you do not ask the user to enter the number of characters for the next input -- instead you use a sufficiently sized temporary buffer to store the input and call `strlen()` on the buffer to get the number of characters)

With `size` containing the number of characters (in your case -- the length of the string), you must allocate `size + 1` bytes to provide room to store the *nul-terminating* character (`'\0'` -- or just plain `0`). You would need:

```
    ...
    ptr->itemName = malloc (size + 1);  /* you must allocate +1 chars for '\0' */

    if (ptr->itemName == NULL) {        /* validate every allocation */
        perror ("malloc-ptr->itemName");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    ...
```

(**note:** on failure `malloc` sets `errno` allowing you to output the error with `perror()`)

Completing your `readItem()` function, you would do:

```
    ...
    printf ("\nSpecify the name of the product (MAX %d letters): ", size);
    if (scanf ("%s", ptr->itemName) != 1) {
        fputs ("error: read error ptr->itemName\n", stderr);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    empty_stdin();              /* empty all extraneous characters from stdin */

    printf ("\nHow many products do the company have? ");
    if (scanf ("%d", &ptr->quantity) != 1) {
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    empty_stdin();              /* empty all extraneous characters from stdin */

    printf ("\nHow expensive is the product? ");
    if (scanf ("%f", &(ptr->price)) != 1) {
        fputs ("error: invalid float input.\n", stderr);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    empty_stdin();              /* empty all extraneous characters from stdin */

    ptr->amount = ptr->price * ptr->quantity;
}
```

Another issue you may want to address is your placement of `'*'` in the declaration of your pointer values. Generally the `'*'` goes with the variable, not the type. Why?

```
int* a, b, c;
```

does NOT declare three pointers to `int`, instead it declares one integer pointer and two integers. Placing the `'*'` with the variable makes that clear, e.g.

```
int *a, b, c;
```

Now putting it altogether and writing a short `printItem()` function, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Item {
    char *itemName;
    int quantity;
    float price;
    float amount;
} Item;

/* function to input stdin to end of line or EOF */
void empty_stdin (void)
{
    int c = getchar();
    
    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}

void readItem (Item *ptr)
{
    int size;
    
    printf ("\nSpecify the amount of letters of the product name: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &size) != 1) {              /* validate every user input */
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    empty_stdin();              /* empty all extraneous characters from stdin */

    ptr->itemName = malloc (size + 1);  /* you must allocate +1 chars for '\0' */

    if (ptr->itemName == NULL) {        /* validate every allocation */
        perror ("malloc-ptr->itemName");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    printf ("\nSpecify the name of the product (MAX %d letters): ", size);
    if (scanf ("%s", ptr->itemName) != 1) {
        fputs ("error: read error ptr->itemName\n", stderr);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    empty_stdin();              /* empty all extraneous characters from stdin */

    printf ("\nHow many products do the company have? ");
    if (scanf ("%d", &ptr->quantity) != 1) {
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    empty_stdin();              /* empty all extraneous characters from stdin */

    printf ("\nHow expensive is the product? ");
    if (scanf ("%f", &(ptr->price)) != 1) {
        fputs ("error: invalid float input.\n", stderr);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    empty_stdin();              /* empty all extraneous characters from stdin */

    ptr->amount = ptr->price * ptr->quantity;
}

void printItem (Item *pitem)
{
    printf ("\nitemName   : %s\n"
            "  quantity : %d\n"
            "  price    : %.2f\n"
            "  amount   : %.2f\n",
            pitem->itemName, pitem->quantity, pitem->price, pitem->amount);
}

int main (void) {
    
    Item sample;
    Item *p_sample = &sample;

    readItem(p_sample);
    printItem(p_sample);

    free(p_sample->itemName);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/readitem

Specify the amount of letters of the product name: 9

Specify the name of the product (MAX 9 letters): lollypops

How many products do the company have? 100

How expensive is the product? .79

itemName   : lollypops
  quantity : 100
  price    : 0.79
  amount   : 79.00
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/readitem
==9619== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==9619== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==9619== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==9619== Command: ./bin/readitem
==9619==

Specify the amount of letters of the product name: 9

Specify the name of the product (MAX 9 letters): lollypops

How many products do the company have? 100

How expensive is the product? .79

itemName   : lollypops
  quantity : 100
  price    : 0.79
  amount   : 79.00
==9619==
==9619== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9619==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9619==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 2,058 bytes allocated
==9619==
==9619== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==9619==
==9619== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==9619== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

**Using fgets() For User-Input**

As noted earlier, there are a number of pitfalls surrounding the user of `scanf()` for user input that inherently results in a fragile input routine at best unless all potential pitfalls are addressed. Using a temporary buffer (sufficiently sized character array) to store user input using `fgets()` and then parsing any values needed with `sscanf()` ensures that a complete line of input is read each time and no extraneous characters remain to cause the next input to fail. It also opens up a number of different methods for parsing the information you want from the temporary buffer in addition to `sscanf()`.

The only caveat to using a *line-oriented* input function is that the functions read and include the `'\n'` (generated by the user pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>) in the buffer they fill. So you simply trim the `'\n'` from the end of the buffer by overwriting it with `'\0'` when you obtain the length of the input. The most reliable method is using `strcspn()`.

Changing the return type for `readItem()` to `int` to allow for an indication of successs or failure to be returned to `main()`, you could do something similar to the following:

```
...
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1024       /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
...
```

Set the size of the temporary buffer by declaring a constant large enough to hold any anticipated user input (including the cat stepping on the keyboard). Don't skimp on buffer size. (reduce accordingly if programming for a microcontroller with limited memory)

The function will return `EOF` if a user generates a manual `EOF` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> on Linux or <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> on windows. The functions returns `0` on success or `1` if any error is encountered allowing you to handle the return in `main()` (you can adjust whether you use `0` for success or failure to suit your needs)

Reading, allocating and copying the input to `ptr->itemName` becomes:

```
int readItem (Item *ptr)
{
    char buf[MAXC];     /* buffer to hold each user input */
    size_t len = 0;     /* length of product name */
    
    fputs ("\nProduct name: ", stdout);             /* fputs all that is needed, no conversions */
    if (fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin) == NULL) {         /* read input into buffer and validate */
        fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stdout);  /* handle error */
        return EOF;                                 /* return EOF if manual EOF generated by user */
    }
    
    len = strcspn (buf, "\n");                      /* get length of chars (includes '\n') */
    buf[len] = 0;                                   /* overwrite '\n' with '\0' */
    
    ptr->itemName = malloc (len + 1);               /* allocate length + 1 bytes */
    if (!ptr->itemName) {                           /* validate allocation */
        perror ("malloc-ptr->itemName");            /* output error (malloc sets errno) */
        return 1;                                   /* return failure */
    }
    
    memcpy (ptr->itemName, buf, len + 1);           /* copy buf to ptr->itemName */
```

(**note:** there is no need to use `strcpy()` to copy to `ptr->itemName` and have `strcpy()` scan for the end-of-string all over again since that was already done in the call to `strcspn()`. Knowing how many bytes you need to copy, you can simply copy that number of bytes with `memcpy()`)

The read an conversion to `int` and `float` are basically identical other than the verbiage and conversion specifier used with `sscanf()`, e.g.

```
    fputs ("Quantity    : ", stdout);               /* prompt and read quantity */
    if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {
        fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stdout);
        return EOF;
    }
    if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &ptr->quantity) != 1) {  /* convert to int with sscanf */
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    
    fputs ("Price       : ", stdout);               /* prompt and read price */
    if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {
        fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stdout);
        return EOF;
    }
    if (sscanf (buf, "%f", &ptr->price) != 1) {     /* convert to float with sscanf */
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
```

All that remains is:

```
    ptr->amount = ptr->price * ptr->quantity;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Putting an equivalent example together using the updated `readItem()`, you would have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1024       /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

typedef struct Item {
    char *itemName;
    int quantity;
    float price;
    float amount;
} Item;

int readItem (Item *ptr)
{
    char buf[MAXC];     /* buffer to hold each user input */
    size_t len = 0;     /* length of product name */
    
    fputs ("\nProduct name: ", stdout);             /* fputs all that is needed, no conversions */
    if (fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin) == NULL) {         /* read input into buffer and validate */
        fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stdout);  /* handle error */
        return EOF;                                 /* return EOF if manual EOF generated by user */
    }
    
    len = strcspn (buf, "\n");                      /* get length of chars (includes '\n') */
    buf[len] = 0;                                   /* overwrite '\n' with '\0' */
    
    ptr->itemName = malloc (len + 1);               /* allocate length + 1 bytes */
    if (!ptr->itemName) {                           /* validate allocation */
        perror ("malloc-ptr->itemName");            /* output error (malloc sets errno) */
        return 1;                                   /* return failure */
    }
    
    memcpy (ptr->itemName, buf, len + 1);           /* copy buf to ptr->itemName */
    
    fputs ("Quantity    : ", stdout);               /* prompt and read quantity */
    if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {
        fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stdout);
        return EOF;
    }
    if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &ptr->quantity) != 1) {  /* convert to int with sscanf */
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    
    fputs ("Price       : ", stdout);               /* prompt and read price */
    if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {
        fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stdout);
        return EOF;
    }
    if (sscanf (buf, "%f", &ptr->price) != 1) {     /* convert to float with sscanf */
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    
    ptr->amount = ptr->price * ptr->quantity;
    
    return 0;
}

void printItem (Item *pitem)
{
    printf ("\nitemName   : %s\n"
            "  quantity : %d\n"
            "  price    : %.2f\n"
            "  amount   : %.2f\n",
            pitem->itemName, pitem->quantity, pitem->price, pitem->amount);
}

int main (void) {
    
    Item sample = { .itemName = "" };

    if (readItem (&sample) != 0)
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    
    printItem (&sample);

    free(sample.itemName);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/readitem_fgets

Product name: lollypops
Quantity    : 100
Price       : .79

itemName   : lollypops
  quantity : 100
  price    : 0.79
  amount   : 79.00
```

It equally handles whitespace separated words as well and strings of any length up to `MAXC - 1` characters:

```
$ ./bin/readitem_fgets

Product name: "My dog has fleas and my cat has none?" (McGraw-BigHill 1938)
Quantity    : 10
Price       : 19.99

itemName   : "My dog has fleas and my cat has none?" (McGraw-BigHill 1938)
  quantity : 10
  price    : 19.99
  amount   : 199.90
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

Same output as above with the same number of bytes allocated and results as shown with the first example.

That, along with the comments I provided, are the basic nuts-and-bolts approaches to user input, the different considerations, and the way you handle allocating for string input. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

***Footnotes:***

**1.** `scanf()` is full of pitfalls for new C programmers. The recommended way to take user input is with a *line-oriented* function like `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()`. That way you can ensure a complete line of input is read and that characters do not remain in your input buffer (`stdin`) in the event of a *matching failure*. A few links discussing the proper use of `scanf`, [C For loop skips first iteration and bogus number from loop scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60472657/3422102) and [Trying to scanf hex/dec/oct values to check if they're equal to user input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47193170/3422102) and [How do I limit the input of scanf to integers and floats(numbers in general)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53727344/3422102)

Comment: This answers helped me so much. Do you know any good memory usage checker for Windows? And I´m already studying this treatments of errors and recommended ways of user-input. Always improving!

Comment: There is a collection of good approaches for windows here [Is there a good Valgrind substitute for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows). Last benefit I forgot to mention with the `fgets()/sscanf()` approach is you get to independently validate (1) the read of information from the user with `fgets()` and (2) the validation of the conversion with `sscanf()`. This allows you to write robust input routines that require to user to enter the correct value by looping continually until that input is provided. Good luck with your coding!