# getchar not working properly after using scanf in C

Tags: c, scanf, getchar

I am writing this code:

```
int b;
char c;

scanf("%d", &b);

while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if(c >= 9 || c < 0) {
        printf("Invalid number!\n");
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

When I assign `b`, automatically `c` is equal to `b`.
For example, if my input for `b` is `10`, it automatically goes into the `if`-statement and exits the code.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Check the return value from `scanf` and go from there

Comment: `getchar` returns an `int`.  You cannot reliably check for EOF if `c` is not of type `int`.

Comment: If your input file is text, it is extremely likely that `c >= 9` is true.  Perhaps you meant `if( c >= '9' || c < '0')` which is very different than `if( c >= 9 || c < 0)`

Comment: What input did you provide?  Did you provide input for `scanf` and `getchar` on separate lines?  If so, `getchar` will be reading the unread newline left behind from `scanf`.  [Just avoid using `scanf`](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html).

Comment: `while (scanf("%d", &b) != 1) { fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr); for (int c = getchar(); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getchar()) {} }`

Comment: A few links discussing the proper use of `scanf`, [C For loop skips first iteration and bogus number from loop scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60472657/3422102) and [Trying to scanf hex/dec/oct values to check if they're equal to user input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47193170/3422102) and [How do I limit the input of scanf to integers and floats(numbers in general)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53727344/3422102)

Comment: Try typing `"10"` then TAB, then Enter.  Note that the enter key usually makes `'\n'` with an ASCII value of 10.

Answer (score 0):

### Finding problems and solving them

**You have plenty of errors in the code that are listed below.**

1. The [`getchar(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar) says:

   > `getchar()` is equivalent to `getc(stdin)`.

   The prototype of `getc()` is:

   ```
   int getc(FILE *stream);
   ```

   That is, the `getchar()` returns an integer (from `unsigned char` cast). Thus, we need to change the type from `char` to `int` to accept its return value correctly.

   **Note that `EOF` is not a valid `unsigned char`.** It expands to `signed int` -1.
2. Never ignore the return value of the [`scanf(3)`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html). It returns the number of correctly passed arguments. In this case, to make the code reliable, we should put:

   ```c
   if (scanf("%d", &b) != 1) {
     fprintf(stderr, "Value must be an integer.\n");
     return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }
   ```
3. There is a semantic error in the condition:

   ```
   if (c >= 9 || c < 0)
         ^^____________ logically, 9 is a valid one digit number
                        so removing '=' from here makes more sense
   ```

   One notable thing is that the condition and the type of the comparator – both should be changed. See the next step.
4. The fixed loop should look like:

   ```c
   while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
     if (c == '\n') // Since c = getchar() can be '\n' too
       continue;    // so, better ignore

     if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') // Change the loop like this
       printf("Valid number %d %c.\n", c, c);
     else
       printf("Invalid number.\n");
   }
   ```

---

### Sample test case output

```
1 
10    // --- Note: 10 are two chars for two getchars
Valid number 49 1.
Valid number 48 0.
3
Valid number 51 3.
9
Valid number 57 9.
- 
Invalid number.
a
Invalid number.
<
Invalid number.
.
Invalid number.
```

Comment: Right idea: use `int c`,  Wrong reason: "Note that EOF is not a valid char! It expands to -1" --> -1 is a valid value for a _signed_ `char`.  `int` needed to distinguish the 256 `unsgined char` values and `EOF`.